# Who will get the paid amount which is paid by Signer in Anchor rust contract?

Tags: anchor, rust

[image]
In this code snippet, Signer will be payer and he will pay when create function is called
I have 2 questions in here
1: If Signer pay according to above code, who will get that paid amount?
2: How can we change the pay balance?

Comment: please replace this screenshot with a text code block. also, everywhere you refer to "signer" here, you mean "fee-payer", please edit accordingly

Comment: I don't understand part 2: How can we change the pay balance? Do you mean: "How can we change the amount to pay"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`payer` here refers to the account that pays the transaction fee to the validator that processes the transaction. if you want the user to pay some amount to some account, you need to explicitly transfer the balance in your code